# Impossible to connect to ProFTPd in PASV mode

Tags: firewall, ftp

I have installed ProFTPd in Ubuntu 18.04

It has been working for monthes. For some reasons, now, this is not working any more with my Go Client.

If I want to connect with Filezilla, it will work as long as I connect in Active mode.

It is weird because in AWS, my Go client is working, running in my Kubernetes cluster, that is not local.

I also had the issue in local, I fixed it changing `localhost` by `127.0.0.1`, I'm not sure why it worked.

But I tried the same thing for distant server, changing ftp.domain.com by the IP, it doesn't work.

AWS Security group is opened to all port, all ip, and ufw is inactive, so there shouldn't have a firewall issue.

Also, I am not using TLS, but plain FTP. All my files are encrypted.

Here is the `proftpd.conf` config file

```
# /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf -- This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file.
# To really apply changes, reload proftpd after modifications, if
# it runs in daemon mode. It is not required in inetd/xinetd mode.
# 

# Includes DSO modules
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

# Set off to disable IPv6 support which is annoying on IPv4 only boxes.
UseIPv6             on
# If set on you can experience a longer connection delay in many cases.
IdentLookups            off

ServerName          "FTP"
# Set to inetd only if you would run proftpd by inetd/xinetd.
# Read README.Debian for more information on proper configuration.
ServerType              standalone
DeferWelcome            off

MultilineRFC2228        on
DefaultServer           on
ShowSymlinks            on

TimeoutNoTransfer       600
TimeoutStalled          600
TimeoutIdle         1200

DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir                .message true
ListOptions                 "-l"

DenyFilter          \*.*/

# Use this to jail all users in their homes 
DefaultRoot         ~

# Users require a valid shell listed in /etc/shells to login.
# Use this directive to release that constrain.
RequireValidShell       off

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21

# In some cases you have to specify passive ports range to by-pass
# firewall limitations. Ephemeral ports can be used for that, but
# feel free to use a more narrow range.
PassivePorts                  49152 65534

# If your host was NATted, this option is useful in order to
# allow passive tranfers to work. You have to use your public
# address and opening the passive ports used on your firewall as well.
# MasqueradeAddress     1.2.3.4

# This is useful for masquerading address with dynamic IPs:
# refresh any configured MasqueradeAddress directives every 8 hours
<IfModule mod_dynmasq.c>
# DynMasqRefresh 28800
</IfModule>

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User                proftpd
Group               nogroup

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
# (second parm) from being group and world writable.
Umask               022  022
# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
AllowOverwrite          on

# Uncomment this if you are using NIS or LDAP via NSS to retrieve passwords:
# PersistentPasswd      off

# This is required to use both PAM-based authentication and local passwords
# AuthOrder         mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c

# Be warned: use of this directive impacts CPU average load!
# Uncomment this if you like to see progress and transfer rate with ftpwho
# in downloads. That is not needed for uploads rates.
#
# UseSendFile           off

TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log

# Logging onto /var/log/lastlog is enabled but set to off by default
#UseLastlog on

# In order to keep log file dates consistent after chroot, use timezone info
# from /etc/localtime.  If this is not set, and proftpd is configured to
# chroot (e.g. DefaultRoot or <Anonymous>), it will use the non-daylight
# savings timezone regardless of whether DST is in effect.
#SetEnv TZ :/etc/localtime

<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
QuotaEngine off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
</IfModule>


# Delay engine reduces impact of the so-called Timing Attack described in
# http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/11430/discuss
# It is on by default. 
<IfModule mod_delay.c>
DelayEngine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
ControlsEngine        off
ControlsMaxClients    2
ControlsLog           /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
ControlsInterval      5
ControlsSocket        /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
AdminControlsEngine off
</IfModule>

#
# Alternative authentication frameworks
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/ldap.conf
#Include /etc/proftpd/sql.conf

#
# This is used for FTPS connections
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/tls.conf

#
# Useful to keep VirtualHost/VirtualRoot directives separated
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/virtuals.conf

# A basic anonymous configuration, no upload directories.

# <Anonymous ~ftp>
#   User                ftp
#   Group               nogroup
#   # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
#   UserAlias           anonymous ftp
#   # Cosmetic changes, all files belongs to ftp user
#   DirFakeUser on ftp
#   DirFakeGroup on ftp
# 
#   RequireValidShell       off
# 
#   # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
#   MaxClients          10
# 
#   # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, and '.message' displayed
#   # in each newly chdired directory.
#   DisplayLogin            welcome.msg
#   DisplayChdir        .message
# 
#   # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
#   <Directory *>
#     <Limit WRITE>
#       DenyAll
#     </Limit>
#   </Directory>
# 
#   # Uncomment this if you're brave.
#   # <Directory incoming>
#   #   # Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
#   #   # (second parm) from being group and world writable.
#   #   Umask               022  022
#   #            <Limit READ WRITE>
#   #            DenyAll
#   #            </Limit>
#   #            <Limit STOR>
#   #            AllowAll
#   #            </Limit>
#   # </Directory>
# 
# </Anonymous>

# Include other custom configuration files
Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/
```

Also, I can check with `netstat -nlpute | grep 21` that FTP is listening port 21:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      113        46129898    28696/proftpd: (acc
```

I tried to load module:

```
sudo /sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
```

as recommended in some pages, and restarted ftp, but it didn't work

UPDATE:

After switching to my 4G connection, my issue has changed:

```
Status: Resolving address of localhost
Status: Connecting to [::1]:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxx.fr
Status: Connecting to xxxxxxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Error:  Could not read from socket: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
Error:  Disconnected from server
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxx.fr
Status: Connecting to xxxxxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Error:  Could not read from socket: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
Error:  Disconnected from server
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

It still works when I choose active transfer mode.

When I do :

```
proftpd -vv
```

I get:

```
2020-08-21 06:48:41,796 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29875]: warning: unknown/unsupported LANG environment variable 'en_US.UTF-8', ignoring
2020-08-21 06:48:41,799 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29875]: mod_ctrls/0.9.5: unable to open ControlsLog '/var/log/proftpd/controls.log': Permission denied
2020-08-21 06:48:41,799 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29875]: fatal: ControlsLog: unable to open '/var/log/proftpd/controls.log': No such file or directory on line 122 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'
```

I don't think none of them will fix my issue.

finally, checking the logs, after a connection reset, I get:

```
2020-08-21 06:55:57,273 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29943] ip-172-31-45-72.eu-west-3.compute.internal (my ip.rev.sfr.net[my ip]): FTP session opened.
2020-08-21 06:55:57,429 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29943] ip-172-31-45-72.eu-west-3.compute.internal (my ip.rev.sfr.net[my ip]): USER sgsource: Login successful.
2020-08-21 06:55:57,613 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29943] ip-172-31-45-72.eu-west-3.compute.internal (my ip.rev.sfr.net[93.23.197.105]): FTP session closed.
2020-08-21 06:55:57,816 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29959] ip-172-31-45-72.eu-west-3.compute.internal (my ip.rev.sfr.net[my ip]): FTP session opened.
2020-08-21 06:55:57,965 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29959] ip-172-31-45-72.eu-west-3.compute.internal (my ip.rev.sfr.net[my ip]): USER sgsource: Login successful.
2020-08-21 06:55:58,190 ip-172-31-45-72 proftpd[29959] ip-172-31-45-72.eu-west-3.compute.internal (my ip.rev.sfr.net[my ip]): FTP session closed.
```

When I connect in SSH to my ftp server, and connect ftp in localhost with:

```
ftp localhost
```

I enter my login / passwd, then:

```
quote PASV
ls
```

And I can see the listing of my files, so it works.

I still don't understand what is happening and what should I do to fix it.

Any help will be appreciated !